# Best way to organize "library" of training documents -- some reside on SP, others in external system(s)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, information-management, training, document-management

trying to figure out how best to present training materials to my users via our SP site.

- I have a wealth of training documents varying from narrated training courses to white papers with no additional context.
- Want to have a single point of contact with my user base where they can access all training materials.
- Best solution I could arrive at is to use a list where users provide a title, short description, and hyperlink to the training document. That hyperlink might take them to a SP doc library or some external data repository.

[image: example list]

Are there other methods I should consider?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A list is great for this. Consider adding a category or product column and then creating a view that groups by that category or product. Or, perhaps a training type (perhaps some are documents and others are videos?). Perhaps another view that sorts by date created descending, so users can see which trainings have been added recently?

Perhaps consider a community site, discussion board, or Yammer group to allow users to ask further questions about which trainings are recommended/required, or to ask further questions about the content. (If you do this, you'll need to do some work recruiting people to participate, as no one is going to start asking questions in a blank forum).